# How can i turn powershell scraping code to a javascript?

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm trying to scrape ticker historical data from this [website](https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BOAS.sn). The powershell code i generate using **copy as Powershell** is showing the desire data but i can get access of the content.
Below is the code :

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_ga", "GA1.2.803303644.1660530733", "/", ".sikafinance.com")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("__gads", "ID=4ebb5b4b4bc3835e:T=1660530733:S=ALNI_MYFKapHKqM5T0wn5xOUyezL5xFUHA", "/", ".sikafinance.com")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_gid", "GA1.2.2040239953.1661115998", "/", ".sikafinance.com")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("__gpi", "UID=00000a839193b21b:T=1660530733:RT=1661115997:S=ALNI_MZzCOONMVTB12hYB66TJDO1paWuqQ", "/", ".sikafinance.com")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_gat", "1", "/", ".sikafinance.com")))
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos" `
-Method "POST" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"authority"="www.sikafinance.com"
  "method"="POST"
  "path"="/api/general/GetHistos"
  "scheme"="https"
  "accept"="*/*"
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
  "cache-control"="no-cache"
  "origin"="https://www.sikafinance.com"
  "pragma"="no-cache"
  "referer"="https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BOAS.sn"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Chromium`";v=`"104`", `" Not A;Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"104`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?1"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Android`""
  "sec-fetch-dest"="empty"
  "sec-fetch-mode"="cors"
  "sec-fetch-site"="same-origin"
} `
-ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8" `
-Body "{`"ticker`":`"BOAS.sn`",`"datedeb`":`"2022-06-24`",`"datefin`":`"2022-08-19`",`"xperiod`":`"0`"}"
```

Belowing is the fetch methode

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    authority: 'www.sikafinance.com',
    accept: '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    cookie: '_ga=GA1.2.803303644.1660530733; __gads=ID=4ebb5b4b4bc3835e:T=1660530733:S=ALNI_MYFKapHKqM5T0wn5xOUyezL5xFUHA; _gid=GA1.2.2040239953.1661115998; __gpi=UID=00000a839193b21b:T=1660530733:RT=1661115997:S=ALNI_MZzCOONMVTB12hYB66TJDO1paWuqQ; _gat=1',
    origin: 'https://www.sikafinance.com',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    referer: 'https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BOAS.sn',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'
  }, mode: "no-cors",
  body: JSON.stringify({
  "ticker": "BOAS.sn",
  "datedeb": "2022-06-24",
  "datefin": "2022-08-19",
  "xperiod": "0"
})
};

fetch('https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos', !0, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When i use the fetch option in other console(one that is different from the website one) i recieve this as result.
[image: Fetch result]
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of powershell output]

Comment: Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: Casraf i add the fetch methode up

Comment: 1: `the fetch methode` does not take THREE arguments ... what makes you think it does? 2: `mode: "no-cors"` guarantees you won't have access to the result, 3: looks like you're running the code in a browser - you can't actually set many of the headers you're trying to set, e.g. cookie, origin, referer, user-agent - not sure about those `sec-` ones either

Comment: I used the three arguments because of their source code. the **no-cors** is just to allow webscraping from another site web console. I'm trying to add the fetch code to my site web. That means the best fetch methode must work in every console